# React Native geolocation heading is always -1 on iPhone 7

Tags: react-native, geolocation, react-native-ios

I am faced an issue that I can't solve for a weeks.

Task: I heed to watch for a device position and its direction.

Solution: I use method as described in docs

```
this.watcher = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
    const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    const heading = position.coords.heading;

    this.setState({
      latitude: latitude,
      longitude: longitude,
      heading: heading
    });
  },
  (error) => {
     console.log(`error: ${error}`);
  }, 
  {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 10000,
    maximumAge: 0
  });
```

Eevrything works fine on simulator. But on a real iOS device heading is always -1.
My project use RN 0.54. However I just created fresh project with RN 0.56 via `react-native init` and behavior is the same.

The thing is that in react-native-maps package user direction renders in a perfect way, so I assume that there may be some issue with React Native

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since React Native geolocation is an extension over web geolocation ([see docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation)),
it gets orientation(heading) as a difference between two last positions. Which is not working at low speed or when user stays (returns -1).

Which is strange, because I expected RN to get device heading from built in "compass".

**Solution for ejected apps**: use thirds party library [react-native-heading](https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-heading) to get device heaing even when user stays.

**Solution for Expo**: there should be no problem like this because Expo use built in compass instead of web geolocation.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Location.getHeadingAsync()` I was able to get a heading direction to not be -1.

Check out this link for the expo method I am using:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location#expolocationgetheadingasync-215

Comment: I do not use expo, I develop ejected rn app